# How can I block all traffic except web traffic?

Tags: iptables, web

I have wrote my rules like this:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

What do I do next?

Answer (score 2):

After you apply the rules that [heikogerlach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658746/how-do-i-block-all-traffics-except-web/658782#658782) showed you, here's a useful link to help you in the future so you understand what you're doing.

- [Quick HOWTO, Ch14: Linux Firewalls Using iptables](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch14_:_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables)
- [Documentation about the netfilter/iptables project](http://www.iptables.org/documentation/index.html)
- [Netfilter IPTables Mini Howto](http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Netfilter_IPTables_Mini_Howto)

Basically, to answer the question you posed in a comment, you need this rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

so that incoming packets that *are a response to a packet sent by your system* will be allowed in.  Otherwise this box won't be able to receive anything except to port 80.

NOTE:  You also have to tell us something additional ... Do you want to block all access except incoming and outgoing web, or only incoming or only outgoing?  What traffic do you want to allow?

Answer (score 1):

Now you are allowed to send packets from your computer to another one with the destination port 80. You must allow responses from the remote computers and you want to receive errors, too.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

You need the kernel module ip_conntrack for connection tracking:

```
modprobe ip_conntrack
```

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

Why this rule is needed?

Comment: This rule means that any traffic, especially incoming traffic, is allowed that belongs to the connection you opened. Otherwise you would not allow any data to come back.

Comment: And you probably want to allow traffic from localhost/127.0.0.1 unless you don't care about all kinds of stuff stopping to work.